# Mixture process conditioned on another mixture process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random

Let $N(T_1)$ is Poisson counting mixture process and $M(T_2)$ is another independent Poisson counting mixture process, such that

$$ N(T_1) \sim (1-p) \cdot \operatorname{P}(\lambda_0T_1)+p \cdot \operatorname{P}(\lambda_1T_1),$$

$$ M(T_2) \sim (1-p) \cdot \operatorname{P}(\lambda_0T_2)+p \cdot \operatorname{P}(\lambda_1T_2),$$

where $0 <p<1$ is a fixed constant, and $T_1$ and $T_2$ are the lengths of *intervals* in which counting is done.

**Question:**  Let    $ U(T_3) \equiv N(T_3)+M(T_3), $

Processes $N$ and $M$ are added first and then counted for time $T_3$. $T_3$ is non over-lapping to $T_1$ and $T_2$.

How to evaluate mass function of conditional random process $U(T_3)\mid N(T_1)$?

Note that time interval $T_3$ is non overlapping to $T_1$ and $T_2.$

Comment: Since $T_3$ and $T_1$ are non-overlapping, $U(T_3)$ is independent of $N(T_1)$.

Comment: @A.S. No. Poisson mixture process is 'stationary' but not 'independent' in non-overlapping time slots.

Comment: You are right. The notation you chose for $M,N$ (is it standard?) is misleading then. Something like $N\sim (1-B)P_0+BP_1$ for Bernoulli B(p) would be much more description and non-misleading.

Comment: $N(T_3)\mid N(T_1)\sim (1-B)P_0(T_3)+BP_1(T_3)$ for $B=B(p')$ where $$\frac{p'}{1-p'}=\frac p{1-p}\frac{e^{-\lambda_1T_1}\lambda_1^{N(T_1)}}{e^{-\lambda_0T_1}\lambda_0^{N(T_1)}}=\frac p{1-p}e^{-(\lambda_1-\lambda_0)T_1}\left(\frac {\lambda_1}{\lambda_0}\right)^{N_1(T_1)}$$ and $M(T_3)$ is independent of $N_1(T_1)$.

Comment: In $N \sim (1-B)P_0+BP_1$, you mean $B$ a random variable (Bernoulli distributed) or a probability value ($p$) at 1?

Comment: $B$ is Bernoulli - as mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: If you mean $B$ a RV then notation ($\sim$) makes no sense. We should then replace $\sim$ by equal sign and similarly $P_0(T_3)$ will be some RV too, instead of a pmf.

Comment: It is your choice of $pX+qY$ to describe a *mixture* of $X$ and $Y$ that doesn't make sense. $(1-B)X+BY$ is *the* way to describe a mixture.

Comment: then what you mean by $P_0$ then? a RV or pmf?

Comment: $P_i(T)=Poisson(\lambda_iT)$

Comment: Ok. Thanks for correcting me. But correct notations are more confusing :)

Comment: See,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Finite_and_countable_mixtures 

When I write $ N(T_1) \sim (1-p) \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}(\lambda_0T_1)+p \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}(\lambda_1T_1),$ I meant  $ f(N(T_1)) =(1-p) \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}(\lambda_0T_1)+p \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}(\lambda_1T_1).$  Is it incorrect according to wikipedia article above? (where $\operatorname{Poiss}$ means a pmf of a poisson distributed RV)

Comment: The usual convention is that random varaibles are denoted by capital letters - $X,B,\text{Poiss}(\lambda)$ - pmf's/pdf's are denoted by $f$ (or $g$) with a subscript - $f_X,f_{P_0}$, cdfs are denoted by $F$ (or $G$), $\sim$ is used for equality in distribution while $=$ is used for actual equality (of r.v. or pmfs or cdsfs) usually and sometimes for equality in distribution slightly sloppily.

Comment: Do you write in answer the derivation you did, and what is $P_0(T_3)$ ?

Comment: I don't understand the first question. The main derivation is: (posterior odds) = (apriori odds) $\times$ (likelihood ratio). I defined $P_i(T)$ above.

Comment: you mean $P_i(T)=\frac{e^{\lambda_i T}(\lambda_i T)^k}{k!}$ where $k$ is some realization of random variable $P_i(T)$.

Comment: Read my previous comment. Capital letters usually refer to *Random Variables* - not pmf's - and I specifically wrote $P_i(T)=Poisson(\lambda_iT)$ for clarity since $P$ can indeed be overloaded. You can describe a random variable with a pmf however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that the parameter selected for $N(T)$, which i will call $\Lambda_{N}$, is equal to $\lambda_{0}$ is

$P(\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{0}|N(T_{1}) = n) = \frac{P(N(T_{1})=n|\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{0})(1 - p)}{P(N(T_{1})=n|\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{0})(1 - p) + P(N(T_{1})=n|\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{1})p}$

This is just Bayes Theorem.

From there we can get:

$$U(T_3)|N(T_1) \sim (1-p) \cdot P(\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{0}|N(T_{1}) = n) \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}(2\lambda_0T_3)+ \\
(1-p) \cdot (1 - P(\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{0}|N(T_{1}) = n)) \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}((\lambda_0 + \lambda_1) T_3)+ \\ \> p \cdot P(\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{0}|N(T_{1}) = n) \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}((\lambda_0 + \lambda_1) T_3)+ p \cdot (1 - P(\Lambda_{N} = \lambda_{0}|N(T_{1}) = n)) \cdot \operatorname{Poiss}(2\lambda_1T_3)$$

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer my question. My question is about conditional probability of $U$ given $N$.

Comment: Yes, and that was the answer I gave.

What does N(T1) tell you about U(T3)?  It gives a posterior distribution on the parameter selected for the N process.  Poisson results in different time-spans are independent, so the only thing to condition on is the unknown parameter selected for N.